# Help me debug this delegatecall Serpent demo I'm working on?

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, serpent, delegatecall

https://gist.github.com/ChrisCalderon/2818e6ba0214c25962b16c02e761dc26

Whenever I try to run it, I get "Transaction Failed". What it's supposed to do is call it's own functions `double` and `half` using delegatecall from function `foo` and then return the result.

Here's the code from the link at the time the question was asked:

```
import serpent
from ethereum import tester as t

code = '''\
def foo(x, flag):
    with prefix = 0:
        if flag == "double":
            prefix = 0x6ffa1caa*2**248
        else:
            prefix = 0x70cd69ae*2**248
        delegate_calldata = alloc(36)
        out = alloc(32)
        mstore(ref(delegate_calldata), prefix / 2**248)
        prefix *= 2**8
        mstore8(ref(delegate_calldata) + 1, prefix / 2**248)
        prefix *= 2**8
        mstore8(ref(delegate_calldata) + 2, prefix / 2**248)
        prefix *= 2**8
        mstore8(ref(delegate_calldata) + 3, prefix / 2**248)
        mstore(ref(delegate_calldata) + 4, x)
        delegatecall(msg.gas, self, 128, 36, 128 + 36, 32)
        return(out[0])
def double(x):
    return(2*x)
def half(x):
    return(x/2)'''

print serpent.compile_to_lll(code)
s = t.state()
c = s.abi_contract(code)
double = int('double'.encode('hex').ljust(64, '0'), 16)
print c.foo(1, double)
```

**UPDATE:** This is the correct way to do it, with the new delegatecall support:

```
import serpent
from ethereum import tester as t

code = '''\
def foo(x, flag):
    with prefix = 0:
        if flag == "double":
            return(self.double(x, call=delegatecall))
        else:
            return(self.half(x, call=delegatecall))
def double(x):
    return(2*x)
def half(x):
    return(x/2)'''

print serpent.compile_to_lll(code)
s = t.state()
c = s.abi_contract(code)
double = int('double'.encode('hex').ljust(64, '0'), 16)
print c.foo(1, double)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vitalik just added support for delegatecall to Serpent, which answers my question by making my method obsolete. You use it by adding `call=delegatecall` to your functions calls.